# Outline of the unpublished proof of Erdős-Sós conjecture

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/418692/130484), it was mentioned that a long time ago, Ajtai, Kolmós, Simonovits, and Szemerédi announced a proof that for sufficiently large $k$, every $k$-vertex tree $T$ is a subgraph of every graph $G$ with average degree $>(k-2)$. However, this was never published.

I was curious if there is a high-level sketch of how their argument should go. I have heard that general outlines were discussed at conferences, but if there is anything in writing I'd appreciate seeing it.

Looking at Section 1.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.06791.pdf), it is suggested that their argument involved "an extension of the regularity lemma", is there a more precise description of the kind of regularity lemma they sought?

Comment: I have not read them in detail, but these slides by Simonovits in 2015 appear to be from a talk sketching their approach: https://imada.sdu.dk/Research/GT2015/Talks/Slides/simonovits.pdf